# Boto3 Cannot Specify Glue Version for Dev Endpoint Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I am trying to use boto3 to launch a glue development endpoint with the following code:

```
import boto3

glueClient = boto3.client('glue', 'us-east-1')

glueClient.create_dev_endpoint(
    EndpointName = name,
    RoleArn = role,
    PublicKey = publicKey,
    NumberOfNodes = 2,
    GlueVersion= "1.0",
    Arguments = {
        "GLUE_PYTHON_VERSION": "3"
    }
)
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "GlueVersion", must be one of: 

EndpointName, RoleArn, SecurityGroupIds, SubnetId, PublicKey, 
PublicKeys, NumberOfNodes, ExtraPythonLibsS3Path, ExtraJarsS3Path, 
SecurityConfiguration, Tags, Arguments
```

Which I understand; It's saying I can't specify the glue version in this way. However, [boto3's docs state otherwise](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_dev_endpoint) and claim that GlueVersion is a valid parameter. What gives? I need spark 2.4 and this way it defaults to Spark 2.2. I've tried adding the GlueVersion parameter in the `Arguments` dict to no avail

EDIT: I should add I am using the latest version of Boto3; 1.14.5

Comment: Your version of boto3 is too out of date. Upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I have, im running 1.14.5

Comment: You might have two versions installed. 1.14.5 did not produce that error message unless somehow you upgraded boto3 without upgrading botocore (which shouldn't be possible)

Comment: How are you passing the public key in the argument. Is this the path of public key in your local machine.